# How to fetch results from CoreData Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, restkit-0.20

This seems like such a simple thing to do but I just can't put it together.  I have an iOS app using RestKit 0.20 to populate my CoreData attributes.  My main view controller is a collection view which is populated at startup by making a request to the server.

When a user selects a cell I am able to transfer the data contained in that cell to the detail view (an image and a title).  But I also need to make another request to the server to obtain all of the information to be shown in the detail viewController.  The Entity name is `Gist` and the Attribute is `fullArticle`

Here is the segue to the `detailViewController`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"newsDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setmanagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];       
    }
}
```

Here is what i use in `-(void)viewDidLoad`

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *articleID =[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"articleId"];
    NSString *personID = [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"userID"];
    NSString *getArticle =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/rest/article/getArticleForView?aid=%@&pid=%@&ip=255.255.255.0",articleID,personID];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:getArticle parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
    NSURL *photoURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
    NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
    self.newsDetailImageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:photoData];

//This is where I am stuck, How do you fetch the Attribute "fullArticle" from the request that I just made?
    self.newsDetailText.text = //valueForKey:"fullArticle" from article with ID `articleID`       

}
```

I have tried using the code below but the `fetchedResultsController` is setup for use with a `tableView` so there is no way I know of to specify without an `indexPath`

```
NSManagedObject *detailText = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:0];
self.newsDetailText.text = [[detailText valueForKey:@"fullArticle"] description];
```

When tried this way `fullArticle` is null presumably because `objectAtIndex:0` is not the right way to designate what object I need to fetch.

Please shed some light on this for me!  Clearly a rookie question so code snippets really help!  Thanks in advance!

***Solution with help from Wain***

Wain pointed out that the request does not take place immediately. I needed to use the callbacks in the request to acquire the data I was wanting.  Restkit provides the `mappingResults` in a variety of ways.  You can read about that [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) under `RKMappingResult`.

Here is how I made it work.

```
//I REPLACE MY SERVER REQUEST WITH THIS     
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:getArticle parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

//HERE IS HOW I SET THE TEXT FIELD IN THE DETAIL VIEW CONTROLLER
    self.newsDetailText.text = [[mappingResult.firstObject valueForKey:@"fullArticle"]description];

// ERROR HANDLING
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you make doesn't get the results from the server immediately. You should implement the callbacks to handle success and error responses and use the supplied mapping result to get the info to display.

Comment: Wain, You are too nice to move right on to my next question.  This is going to show how much I actually know... The callbacks are the `success` and `error` parameters in the request I make right?  Also it hadn't occurred to me that the request wasn't done immediately.  I did notice that when I show the mapping results in the log they do not display until after the view is loaded.  Don't know why I didn't pick up on that.  I will revisit the `RKMappingResult` documentation to try and decipher how to implement it into the callbacks.

Comment: The mapping result is basically just an array, provided to you by the callback, of the objects returned in the download.

Comment: Wain!  I don't know why I couldn't put this together yesterday but your callbacks comment was spot on.  Thanks for the patience and consistency.  Checkmark goes to you and I'll edit my post to show how to use them.  Thanks again.